# Combine values from different feed items

Tags: pipe, yahoo

using XPATH Fetch page I managed to get this output after fetching an html table

```
0
content $59,00
1
content $61,00
2
content $1.873,25
3
content $2.460,70
4
content US$1,49
```

I would like to do some math on this values, like (assuming [#] to be the element index):

```
{ [3] + 50 / ([0] + [1])/2) }
```

or

```
{ [4] + 50 / ([0] + [1])/2) }
```

I don't care about item [4].

I'm thinking I'll have to first remove the currency symbols somehow, then find a way to parse this values into the simple math module. Any clues?

Some context: I've experimented with pipes in the past (several years ago), but that was only combining feeds, not doing any math. I came back to pipes today as I found about the XPATH Fetch  module, which looked interesting, but got stuck with this apparently simple exercise.

Here is the pipe's link so you can see where I am (clue: not very far...) : 
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=06780ca250e5b107b7c1ef52455996ff

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question - do you have a large list of values, each with an element index (from 0 to 4) before it? Or do you always have only 10 lines, but the $ values change each time?

I will assume the latter case - i.e. you get this table once per HTML file, and now want to get a single number from it.

I would use something like this:

```
... | tr -d '.$' | tr ',\n' '. ' | sed 's/content/c/g' | sed 's/0 c \(.*\) 1 c \(.*\) 2 c \(.*\) 3 c \(.*\) 4 c \(.*\)/\4 + 50\/(\1 + \2)\n/' | bc -l
```

explanation:

- first remove the '$' sign and the '.' using `tr -d'
- then transform the ',' into a dot '.', and remove the newlines (make everything a single line)
- then I shorten the "content" to "c", just to make the next part shorter
- I use `sed` to split the fields and take write the mathematical expression with the values
- NOTE - I could have used `cut` as well, if I'd have added the '+/()' symbols
- lastly, I take the resulting expression and pipe it into `bc`. Could have used `python` as well, but I like `bc`

Comment: Hey thanks cluracan, but I'n not sue how to make this happen in yahoo pipes.